# file not found error while accesing a restored site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, restore

We have 2 environments for SharePoint 2013: production and test environment
I did a backup for a site collection in the production environment and I restored it in the test environment.

but when I access the site collection, I have got a "file not found" error.
how can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you see any other content on the site collection or is that error the only thing that you see? Did you inspect the SP logs using the correlation ID provided with the error?

Comment: no the error is the only thing that appears and i got this error when expecting the log file : Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed cache for '0).w|s-1-5-21-3714614052-1110681367-3067802826-1136'.(This is expected during the process warm up or if data cache Initialization is getting done by some other thread).

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to check

- as this is your Test farm, I would reset IIS and see if it brings the site back.
- Check from central admin, if site is listed under view all site collections. Also make sure your root site collection is exist.
- Detach the Content database in which this site is provisioned then attach it again.
- also check the App Pool accounts have permission on the Content Database.
- If nothing help then check the ULS logs and share.

Comment: i did reser IIS but it still doesn't work, the site collection exists under view all site collections and it's the root site collection, i detached the content database and attached it again and  the app pool account have permission on the content database but the same error apeared, checking the ULS code I got this error :

Comment: 04/24/2017 10:58:17.78 w3wp.exe (0x1CEC) 0x0050 SharePoint Foundation DistributedCache air4a Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed cache for '0).w|s-1-5-21-3714614052-1110681367-3067802826-1136'.(This is expected during the process warm up or if data cache Initialization is getting done by some other thread). ba15eb9d-49b3-90b7-2d8a-dbda998c7645